# TailwindCSS doesn't purge plugin classes

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I was trying to reduce the size of my CSS file using Tailwind's in-house compiler. This is my config file:

```js
module.exports = {

  content: ["./pages/*.html", "./components/**/*", "./src/*"],

  mode: "jit",

  plugins: [
    require("tailwindcss"),
    require("tw-elements/dist/plugin"),
    require('tailwind-scrollbar')({ nocompatible: true }),
    function ({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant("child", "& > *");
      addVariant("child-hover", "& > *:hover");
    },
  ],
  },
};
```

I have checked that the directories specified in `content` don't contain any hidden classes, however, it seems that Tailwind includes every class from the package `tw-elements` and doesn't purge them.

Is there any way how I can get a clean CSS file?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI, the config for Tailwind v3 no longer uses the `mode` property, because that version always uses the JIT compilation. You could try updating if you're running an older version. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide